# Subtracting inequalities?

Tags: inequality

I have the following problem:

```
y > 15x + a
y < 5x + b
(1, 20) is a solution to the system. What could be the value of b - a?
```

The answer choices are $(6, 8, 10, 12)$.

Pretty simple. Here's what I've came up with:

```
a < 5
b > 15
```

What I don't understand is how can I answer the question? How can I go from these inequalities to $b - a$ ?

hint: the answer sheet says that $b - a > 15 - 5$. But why greater than? And not greater or equal? I don't really understand the logic here.

Comment: $a < 5$ so $-a > -5$.  And $b > 15$.  So $b+(-a) > 15 +(-5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $<$ is transitive; that is, if $A<B$ and $B<C$, then $A<C$. Combining the two lines, this gives us $15x+a<y<5x+b$, which is the same as $15x-5x=10x<b-a$. Since $x=1$ is a solution, then $10(1)<b-a$. In other words, $b-a=12$.

Alternatively, if $a<5$ and $b>15$, then $b-\{\text{something smaller than 5}\}$ will be greater than $15-5$.

Comment: Thank you! Much clearer now.